# How do I append a binary file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This question relates to Project Euler, Problem 10: sum all the primes below two million. Before I used the right algorithm the program was very slow so I decided to write the primes it found to a data file in batches. Now I have the correct main algorithm but on principle I want to know how to append the data file.

```
#Project Euler 10a: list primes below 2,000,000.

import pickle

def numprime(x):
    for i in range(2, int(x**0.5)+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True

def growfile(primes, faccess):
    file = open('primelist2kk.dat', faccess)
    pickle.dump(primes, file)
    file.close()

def main(fchunk, faccess):
    #File input broken up for memory
    for i in range(10):
        plist = []
        for j in range(1, fchunk, 2):
            k = fchunk*i + j
            if numprime(k):
                plist.append(k)
        if i == 0:
            plist.pop(0)
            plist.insert(0,2)
        print()
        print(plist)
        growfile(plist, faccess)

def viewfile(faccess):
    g = open('primelist2kk.dat', faccess)  
    h = pickle.load(g)
    g.close()
    print(h)
    g.closed


#Supply 1/10 of the prime upper bound
#main(200, 'ab')
viewfile('rb')
```

I've tried every different sensible combination of file access codes I can think of but nothing works. Either subsequent data chunks delete the first one or they don't get saved at all. Any ideas?

NB Unhash main() to create the file and display the program output. Hash main() and unhash viewfile() to view the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your file using append mode (`ab`), but that's not enough. Each binary chunk of data that is written by `pickle.dump` will be independent. When you do a `pickle.load` on the file opened for reading, you'll only get the first one. You need to do a loop and keep loading data until there is no more left.

```
def viewfile():
    with open('primelist2kk.dat', 'rb') as g:
        try:
            while True: # run until there's an exception
                h = pickle.load(g)
                print(h)
        except EOFError: # this will be raised by load() when there's no more data
            pass
```

If you don't want each chuck to print separately, you could probably combine them in a single list.

Answer (score 0):

You need append mode. ie.

```
faccess = 'ab'
```

Aside: [Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a faster way to generate those primes

example of the sieve

```
N = range(2000000)
P = []
for i in N:
    if i > 1:
        P.append(i)
        N[::i] = [0]*((len(N)+i-1)//i)

print P
```

Comment: That's the one that doesn't work, unless the program is reading the file in the wrong way. Thanks for the aside.

Comment: @mistermarko, possibly you _are_ reading it the wrong way. Can you show the updated code?

Comment: The code hasn't changed. Viewfile only prints out the first chunk of data. If anyone gets the code to both save and print out all of the intended data please say so!

Comment: yes, you need to do `pickle.load()` for each chunk as @Blckknght suggests